# Set values to form builds by zend framework

Tags: forms, zend-framework, edit

I use Zend framework to build the forms, I want to make the edit action, since the user click on edit, the form appears with users data, how can I set the data to the form which is built dynamically??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$form->populate($data);
```

where $data is an array of key value pairs containing your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$form = new Zend_Form;

if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
   //to just populate
   $form->populate($this->_getAllParams());

   //or auto populate during validation
   if ($form->isValid($this->_getAllParams()) {
      //do stuff if valid
   }
}
```

I know that ZF maunal is pretty messy and not everything is clear, but I think forms are explained pretty nice (with examples). You should research more by yourself.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$Menu = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Menu(); 
$row = $Menu->fetchRow($Menu->select()->where('id = ?', $id));
$Addmenu = new Admin_Form_Addmenu(); 
$Addmenu->populate($row->toArray());
```